# how to populate nested objects

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am using MERN stack.
I have to populate the objects that was in pair of object the following is my schema.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
rounds:{
   t_tag:{
        type:String,
    },
schedule:[
    {
        teamone:{
            type:ObjectId,
            ref:"Team"
        },
        teamtwo:{
            type:ObjectId,
            ref:"Team"
        },
    }
```

}
]

i have to populate teamone and teamtwo. I have tried the following code.

```
.populate({
    path:'rounds',
    populate:{
        path:'schedule',
        model:"Team",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call populate and pass the ref as the argument, this should populate all objects from the same collection:

```
.populate("Team")
```

In your example:

```
.populate({path:"Team"})
```

For multiple paths you can simply chain the populate method:

```
.populate({path:"Team"}).populate({path:"Some other ref"})
```

Comment: no that doesn't work it just returns the object id